# PHPUnit 9 - Mocking void methods

Tags: unit-testing, methods, mocking, phpunit

I just upgraded the `phpunit 7.5.20` to `phpunit 9.5.0` and I'm facing a lot of errors (good ones actually), but not 100% sure how to workaround with some of those errors.
Just looking for some ideas to fix the following error:

`Method setDummyStuff may not return value of type NULL, its return declaration is "void"`

It happens only when you're creating a `createConfiguredMock()` and passing a `null` method as a argument.

Here's my test:

```
<?php


use Lib\IDummyCode;

class DummyTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testDummyThatReturnsVoid()
    {
        $this->createConfiguredMock(IDummyCode::class, [
            'setDummyStuff' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here's the dummy class:

```
<?php


namespace Lib;

interface IDummyCode
{
    public function setDummyStuff(
        int $testInt,
        string $testString
    ): void;
}
```

Do you guys, have some thoughts about how to improve this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter to `createConfiguredMock` takes an associative array where the key is the method to mock and the value is the value the method should return. Since the `setDummyStuff` method can not return anything (void return type) it does not make sense to define a return value. It isn't the `null` value in particular. It will fail with any value.

So you could just leave that method out:

```
$mock = $this->createConfiguredMock(IDummyCode::class, []);
```

Which can also be written in a nicer way:

```
$mock = $this->createStub(IDummyCode::class);
```

If you need to verify that `setDummyStuff` was called, you have to set up an expectation.

```
$mock = $this->createMock(IDummyCode::class);
$mock->expects(self::once())
     ->method('setDummyStuff')
     ->with(123, 'Hello');
```

Comment: Awesome @PhilipWeinke ! You solve my questions. I'm refactoring/upgrading the entire test suite and I notice the approach that I've described across many many tests :( 
It's a great opportunity to fix the tests and re-educate the other devs how to deal with void methods. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help